# Simon says in Unity

Tags: c#, game, .net, unity3d, simon-says

I've made the Simon says game in Unity

[image]

You start by guessing a pattern of 3 colors and each time you complete the pattern a new, random one, is generated and the length of the pattern is incremented by 1.

The game utilises a custom generic collection I wrote `CircularListNavigator<T>`. I also have a question about it [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/137968/98577)

```
public class CircularListNavigator<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _circularListNavigator = new List<T>();

    private int lastUsedElementIndex;

    public T MoveNext()
    {
        int temp = lastUsedElementIndex;
        lastUsedElementIndex = lastUsedElementIndex + 1 >= _circularListNavigator.Count ? 0 : lastUsedElementIndex + 1;
        return _circularListNavigator[temp];
    }

    public T MovePrevious()
    {
        int temp = lastUsedElementIndex;
        lastUsedElementIndex = lastUsedElementIndex - 1 < 0 ? _circularListNavigator.Count - 1 : lastUsedElementIndex - 1;
        return _circularListNavigator[temp];
    }

    public T Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _circularListNavigator.Count == 0 ? default(T) : _circularListNavigator[lastUsedElementIndex];
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lastUsedElementIndex = 0;
    }

    public CircularListNavigator(int startingIterableIndex = 0)
    {
        lastUsedElementIndex = startingIterableIndex;
    }

    public CircularListNavigator(IEnumerable<T> source, int startingIterableIndex = 0)
    {
        _circularListNavigator = source.ToCircularListNavigator();
        lastUsedElementIndex = startingIterableIndex;
    }

    public CircularListNavigator<T> ConvertToCircularListNavigator(IEnumerable<T> collection, int startingIterableIndex)
    {
        CircularListNavigator<T> iterableCollection = new CircularListNavigator<T>(startingIterableIndex);
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            iterableCollection.Add(item);
        }
        return iterableCollection;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _circularListNavigator[index]; }
        set { _circularListNavigator[index] = value; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _circularListNavigator.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _circularListNavigator.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return _circularListNavigator.IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _circularListNavigator.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _circularListNavigator.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _circularListNavigator.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _circularListNavigator.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _circularListNavigator.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _circularListNavigator.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _circularListNavigator.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _circularListNavigator.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

It has only 1 extension method which converts an `IEnumerable<T>` to `CircularListNavigator<T>`

```
public static CircularListNavigator<T> ToCircularListNavigator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    CircularListNavigator<T> circularListNavigator = new CircularListNavigator<T>();
    foreach (object item in collection)
    {
        circularListNavigator.Add((T)item);
    }
    return circularListNavigator;
}
```

The actual game logic is held in a single class `SimonHandler`

```
public class SimonHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text WinLossText;
    public Button[] Buttons;
    public float ShowDuration;

    private CircularListNavigator<int> indexOrder;
    private const int startingMoveCount = 3;
    private int movesCount;

    private readonly System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (Button button in Buttons)
        {
            button.GetFrameSelected().enabled = false;
        }
        movesCount = startingMoveCount;
        StartGame();
    }

    private void StartGame()
    {
        indexOrder = new CircularListNavigator<int>();
        int number = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < movesCount; i++)
        {
            indexOrder.Add(number);
            number++;
            if (number > Buttons.Length - 1)
            {
                number = 0;
            }
        }
        indexOrder = new CircularListNavigator<int>(Shuffle(indexOrder));
        StartCoroutine(AwaitShowPattern());
    }

    private IEnumerator AwaitShowPattern()
    {
        string order = string.Empty;
        indexOrder.Reset();
        SetButtonInteractivity(false);
        int currentMove = 0;
        while (currentMove < movesCount)
        {
            order += indexOrder.Current;
            Buttons[indexOrder.Current].GetFrameSelected().enabled = true;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(ShowDuration);
            Buttons[indexOrder.Current].GetFrameSelected().enabled = false;
            indexOrder.MoveNext();
            currentMove++;
            yield return null;
        }
        WinLossText.text = "Playing..";
        Debug.Log(order);
        SetButtonInteractivity(true);
    }

    private void SetButtonInteractivity(bool value)
    {
        foreach (Button button in Buttons)
        {
            button.interactable = value;
        }
    }

    public void PressButton(Button button)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(Buttons, button);
        if (index == indexOrder.Current)
        {
            if (indexOrder.Count <= 1)
            {
                WinLossText.text = "Win";
                movesCount++;
                StartGame();
            }
            else
            {
                indexOrder.Remove(indexOrder.Current);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            WinLossText.text = "Loss";
            movesCount = startingMoveCount;
            StartGame();
        }
    }

    private IList<T> Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
    {
        int n = array.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int r = i + (int) (rnd.NextDouble()*(n - i));
            T t = array[r];
            array[r] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
        return array;
    }
}
```

There is one additional extension method used here `GetFrameSelected<T>` which is implemented as follows :

```
public static Image GetFrameSelected<T>(this T source) where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    return source.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>().SingleOrDefault(img => img.name == "Frame");
}
```

I'm looking for comments/improvements/tips on the game logic or the collection regrading code-style primarily, since performance doesn't concern me that much as the game is rather short and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> private readonly IList<T> _circularListNavigator = new List<T>();
> ```

This isn't a navigator yet. I suggest naming it simply `values`.

---

> ```
> public Text WinLossText;
> public Button[] Buttons;
> public float ShowDuration;
> ```

Ouch! `public` non-static non-readonly fields.

---

> ```
> private void StartGame()
> {
>     indexOrder = new CircularListNavigator<int>();
>     int number = 0;
>     for (int i = 0; i < movesCount; i++)
>     {
>         indexOrder.Add(number);
>         number++;
>         if (number > Buttons.Length - 1)
>         {
>             number = 0;
>         }
>     }
>     indexOrder = new CircularListNavigator<int>(Shuffle(indexOrder));
>     StartCoroutine(AwaitShowPattern());
> }
> ```

You use the the `CircularListNavigator` twice here but you discard the first one.  I think using a `List<T>` to collect the `number`s would be enough and then you can use this list to shuffle it and create the navigator.

---

One more thing about it. I think the loop is a good candidate for a general purpose extension, I named it `TakeOrRepeat`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeOrRepeat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, int count)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
    var moveNext = new Func<bool>(() =>
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Could not move-next. Reset enumerator and try again.
        enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    });

    while (counter++ < count)
    {
        if (moveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
        else
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you made the `Shuffle` method an extension too, the `StartGame` method could then be reduced to just a few lines of code of mostly LINQ:

```
var indicies = 
    Enumerable
    .Range(0, Buttons.Length)
    .TakeOrRepeat(movesCount)
    .ToList()
    .Shuffle();
indexOrder = new CircularListNavigator<int>(indicies);
StartCoroutine(AwaitShowPattern());
```

or if you like to just *two* because you already have one more extension the `ToCircularListNavigator`:

```
indexOrder = 
    Enumerable
    .Range(0, Buttons.Length)
    .TakeOrRepeat(movesCount)
    .ToList()
    .Shuffle()
    .ToCircularListNavigator();
StartCoroutine(AwaitShowPattern());
```

---

> ```
> private IList<T> Shuffle<T>(IList<T> array)
> ```

In cases like this the parameter is usually named just `values`. The name `array` is a little bit confusing.

---

> ```
> public static CircularListNavigator<T> ToCircularListNavigator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
> {
>     CircularListNavigator<T> circularListNavigator = new CircularListNavigator<T>();
>     foreach (object item in collection)
>     {
>         circularListNavigator.Add((T)item);
>     }
>     return circularListNavigator;
> }
> ```

If you made the `item` of type `T` then you woundn't need the cast... **but** the 
`CircularListNavigator` already has a constructor that accepts a collection... **but** it uses the extension. This is a vicious circle.

You should move the loop into the constructor or use the `List<T>.AddRange(..)` or even better use the `new List<T>(..)` constructor to initilize it from the `source`.

The `CircularListNavigator` should not depend on the extension. The extension should depend on the `CircularListNavigator`.

Comment: TL;DR field are ok in Unity .I agree on most of your points except for *Ouch! public non-static non-readonly fields.*, public fields are a little bit more special in Unity if you make the field public or use the `[SerializeField]` attribute your field will show up in the inspector which is quite important if you dont want magic numbers and since object inheriting `MonoBehaviour` cant be instantiate this is your only way of settings values, I honestly hate this so much, I either need to make a `[SerializeField]`private variable to back my property or I need to use a public field..

Comment: @denis I had googled for this before I commented because I my gut toldm those fields might be related to unity but when I saw they were using properties in their examples I wasn't sure anymore... I didn't think it might be because of the serialization. I'm inclined to support your field-decision after all ;-]

Comment: Maybe in the video you've watched they're class was not inheriting from `MonoBehaviour` or they just didn't want the variable to be initialized from the editor. It really depends if the project is big I'm always using properties even if I need to create 2 variables for the same purpose, but here the project is really small and having a property with a private field would've just added more unnecessary lines..

Comment: Oh btw there should definitely be a check if the `IEnumerable<T> values .Count()` > 0 else it will cause infinite loop.

Comment: @denis you're right, sorry, this was the old extension, I posted an improved version. I works without `Count`. If it could not `MoveNext` twice then there is nothing to enumerate.

Comment: How can I offer a different approach to the same method ? I still don't quite like it..

Comment: @denis wchich method do you mean? the take-or-repeat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50720/discussion-between-denis-and-t3chb0t).